# Custom created Magento controller link to 404

Tags: php, magento, controller, router

after no sleep night full of googling and trying things, I need your help.
My created controller for Magento 1.9, is inaccessible at the address: 
http://magento1.at/customblog/test/test

```
domain/frontname/controllername/actionname
```

I have already tried running this on windows and mac, repaired permissions of every file and folder, admin panel logout-login, clearing cache, reindexing data, checking my code, and still no luck. The module btw is working, I can Enable/Disable it in admin, and the install script worked with no problems.
So. please, tell me where my problem is at, thanks, everyone so much!
Here is my code:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_CustomBlog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Atwix_CustomBlog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Atwix_CustomBlog>
                <class>Atwix_Customblog_Helper</class>
            </Atwix_CustomBlog>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <customblog>
                <class>Atwix_Customblog_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customblog_resource</resourceModel>
            </customblog>
            <customblog_resource>
                <class>Atwix_Customblog_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <block>
                        <table>atwix_article</table>
                    </block>
                </entities>
            </customblog_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <atwix_customblog_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Atwix_Customblog</module>
                </setup>
            </atwix_customblog_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Atwix_Customblog</module>
                    <frontName>customblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </customblog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**TestController.php**

```
<?php
class Atwix_CustomBlog_TestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function TestAction()
    {
        echo('test');
    }
}
```

Comment: just guessing: it seems a problem.first you have a typo in the tag <use> where you've written starndart instead of standarD. Then it seems a problem of routing, but i cannot see any other problem in the defined route. Does yourdomain/customblog/ url works? or is also a 404?

Comment: corrected my typo, thanks=) at the url yourdomain/customblog/ I still get the "whoops, our bad..." page, so it's not working too

Comment: uh also careful to upper/lowercase-> the class name should be equal to the module name, and in the module.xml is defined as Atwix_Customblog, and the classname is Atwix_CustomBlog. Try to choose one and retry.

Comment: The problem is solved, there was an uppercase/lowercase letters issue in config.xml, thanks everyone!=)

Comment: I put my comments as an answer as it solved the problem. Please accept it to help others understand their problems. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to have a look to two typos in your router section in `module.xml`

You wrote standart instead of standard inside `<use>` tag

```
<use>standard</use>
```

Also careful to upper/lower case letters: in `module.xml` you write `Customblog` everywhere, whereas the class name is `CustomBlog`: you have to make them uniform and change one of the two.